# Stream and play wav audio in browser from downloadable URL without .wav extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I have a URL which points to an audio (.wav) file on the server. The URL is something like http://server.serverdomain.com/FFFFF7B545531555522 without .wav extension. When I hit this URL in the address bar it downloads the file (.wav) on my machine. But, when I use this URL in an audio tag and load it in the browser the audio tag is disabled and I am unable to play the file.

My task is to stream and play the audio from the URL without downloading the referenced file on my local machine.

Note: Above mentioned URL is just a path to an audio file on the server. Similar URL is used to point to any type of file (e.g. text file) on the server depending upon the requirement.

Comment: Provide the link of your file please

Comment: “File names” are irrelevant when it comes to HTTP. Check if the server returns the resource with a correct Content-Type header - _that_ is what determines what “type” the resource will be considered to be of.

Comment: @Disfigure - The URL is similar to one mentioned above, I cannot expose the exact URL as it is development server URL

Comment: @CBroe is right, maybe its just the file type which block the audio tag

Comment: @SaurabhVerma did you find a answer for this ?